# Reflect non-imported class

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

I'm trying to get the properties of a dynamic Class name (also trying to instantiate it) but the next code doesn't work because I think I need to import the dart file that has the Class code in the file where I want to reflect it:

```
//I import the file in other Dart file
import 'MyClass.dart'; //This only have a class named MyClass with some properties
import 'OtherClass.dart'

class mainClass {
  void mainFunction () {
    var properties = OtherClass.getProperties('MyClass');
  }
}
```

Here is the OtherClass contents:

```
import "dart:mirrors";

class OtherClass {
  static getProperties (String className) {
    ClassMirror cm = reflectClass(className);
    for (var m in cm.declarations.values)
      print(MirrorSystem.getName(m.simpleName));
  }
}
```

is there anyway to reflect a class that is not imported in the actual Dart file?

Hope this makes sense, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to find the library containing the class first. Use `currentMirrorSystem().libraries` to get all libraries imported in your application. If you want to avoid disambiguities, add unique library declarations to your library and pass the library name to `getProperties()` for exact lookups.

```
import "dart:mirrors";

class OtherClass {
  static getProperties(String className) {
    var classSymbol = new Symbol(className);
    var libs = currentMirrorSystem().libraries;
    var foundLibs = libs.keys.where((lm) =>
        libs[lm].declarations.containsKey(classSymbol) &&
            libs[lm].declarations[classSymbol] is ClassMirror);
    if (foundLibs.length != 1) {
      throw 'None or more than one library containing "${className}" class found';
    }
    ClassMirror cm = libs[foundLibs.first].declarations[classSymbol];
    for (var m
        in cm.declarations.values) print(MirrorSystem.getName(m.simpleName));
  }
}
```

Comment: What Günther says. Also, I'd recommend passing the name of the class as a Symbol, not a string.

Comment: But `import 'MyClass.dart';` is still required, even if it is not explicitly used in code? - by that I mean `MyClass` is for example only instantiated using `mirrors`.

Comment: @marcinj no, it shouldn't be necessary to import `MyClass.dart`.